# How to call "payable function" via interface in solidity

Tags: solidity, payable, interfaces

I have a function marked as payable in contract A and I want to call it from contract B so that `msg.value` in contract A can have its desired value and contract A must have balance of sent amount , how it is possible ?

Comment: Well... Does it?

Comment: this suggested link s contract level payable handling, I am looking for function level payable handling and via interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you handle amount sending between contracts via interface:

**ContractA.sol:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract A {
    uint256 public lastFundSentToContract = 0;
    
    function updateLastFundSentToContract () public payable {
        lastFundSentToContract = msg.value;
    }
    
    function getContractBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

**ContractB.sol:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract B {
    A a_contract_instance;
    constructor(address _a_contract_address) public {
        a_contract_instance = A(_a_contract_address);
    }
    
    function callToContractA() public payable {
        a_contract_instance.updateLastFundSentToContract.value(msg.value)();
    }
    
    function getContractBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}

interface A {
    function updateLastFundSentToContract () external payable;
}
```